# Is it possible using ROS as fully CLoud system?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI I am now doing my PhD in Cloud Robotic I would like to use ROS as full cloud system with out use other cloud like openstack for instance, and if that possible is there are any ideas how I could start
need to your suggestion
My regards
Hamza

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219839/is-it-possible-using-ros-as-fully-cloud-system?/) by [Hamza Aagela](https://answers.ros.org/users/24874/hamza-aagela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the highest level, ROS provides message pub/sub, central configuration and RPC.

OpenStack and AWS provide service likes file/object storage, virtual machines, and databases.

These are entirely different types of software and applications, and they cannot replace one another.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1